# S4R or S4R5 for general shell stiffness section?

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to calculate the buckling load of a shell model. I want to use general shell stiffness section. So, which shell element type should I choose, S4R or S4R5? what's the differences between them?
Thanks very much!